# Convert nested JSON into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I wish to transform a nested JSON into a dataframe for pandas.

i tried using json_normalize(), but it does not work. i tried using it as shown in [this tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas). perhaps i am defining the parent node incorrectly, given that my json has more depth than the example

```
with open(json_pathfile) as f:

    data_json = json.load(f)
```

​

The nested json looks something like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "allOpportunityApplication": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "person": {
                        "id": "659642",
                        "opportunity_applications_count": 13,
                        "status": "applied"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "person": {
                        "id": "3620882",
                        "opportunity_applications_count": 4,
                        "status": "applied"
                    }
                },
...
```

when using

```
flat_json = json_normalize(data_json['data'])
flat_json.head(3)
```

The output is a single cell.

i wish to have a dataframe with `id`, `opportunity_applications_count` and `status` as columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use fully qualified path of the node you wish to extract. In your case:

```
flat_json = json_normalize(json_data['data']['allOpportunityApplication']['data'])
flat_json.head(3)
```